# I have a problem with Gulp and the Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, gulp, terminal-emulator

I have been using gulp.js for some time and everything was fine, but today by inserting this code I saw that it gave me this problem:

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkmNx.png)

can you tell me why? how do i solve this problem?

[Package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOW0y.png)

[gulpfile 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcz29.png)[gulpfile 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ofbh.png)

Translated error:

I'm sorry if the error is in Italian! I immediately translate anyway:
gulp: Term 'gulp' not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, executable program or script file. Check the spelling of the name or verify that the
path is included and correct, then try again.
In row: 1 car: 1

- gulp watch
- ```
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (gulp: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry if the error is in Italian! I immediately translate anyway:
gulp: Term 'gulp' not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, executable program or script file. Check the spelling of the name or verify that the
path is included and correct, then try again.
In row: 1 car: 1
+ gulp watch
+ ~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (gulp: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException

Comment: What do you get when you do `gulp -v`?  Gulp has to be installed locally and globally.

Comment: @Mark If PowerShell doesn't recognize `gulp` as a command, you would get the same error with `gulp -v`, no?

Comment: Yes, it is just another easy test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the `gulp-cli` package to use the `gulp` command. To do so, you can use `npm i -g gulp-cli` (or `yarn global add gulp-cli` if you use yarn) to install the `gulp` command.

Comment: I tried to install it also, turning on Google I found the same solution but nothing is wrong ...

Comment: If you're sure you've installed the cli already, this is happening most likely because the packages aren't linked to your PATH. To do this, you'll need to add npm's bin directory. You can locate this by running `npm bin -g` in PowerShell. Then, copy the resulting path and add it to your PATH environment variable (This tutorial will show you how: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) Once you've done that, create a *new* PowerShell instance and try running gulp again.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!  this last tip helped me and allowed me to work!  thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Always here to help